# Dajngo - how set index page as http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment, django-urls

I would like to set in Django a URL that will point to my index.html.
Now I could see at http://127.0.0.1:8000/micromundos but I would like to configure the url to show micromundos at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

This is my current myapp/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('micromundos/', include("myapp.urls")),
       ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is myapp/myapp/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "micromundos"
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: add this `path("", views.index, name="index")` in your myapp/urls.py and make the appropriate import .

Comment: Do you know why is not working in production? I've deployed the project on heroku. Locally it works but on production is giving error?

Comment: you're free to ask another question. include proper error details in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just omit `micromundos` in `path('', include("myapp.urls"))` from `myapp/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include("myapp.urls")),
       ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you know why is not working in production? I've deployed the project on heroku. Locally it works but on production is giving error?